# Detect screen protector in Android programmatically

Tags: android

Is there any way where I can inspect that a given device is using screen protector or not. Here the screen protector is generally we use tempered glass on our phone. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have too many tags, pick one

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do unless there's a sensor for detecting it integrated in the screen or the body of the phone, since usually screen protectors doesn't affect touch screen, it might be possible with external sensor, but it needs to be very accurate in detecting transparent layers.